# Http Request Timeout When Inserting Large Spreadsheet Based Dataset Into Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework-core

I am currently working on importing a large (50000 record) excel spreadsheet into a SQL Server database. I'm currently using ExcelDataReader to handle converting the file to a data set, then to Data Table and then to a List. Using Entity Framework Core to save changes the database. This procedure is called via an Http method that looks something like this.

```
[HttpGet("import-file")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ImportData() {
    try {
        // connection string builder here
        var import = new ImportClass(someArgs);

        // introduced http client to attempt extending timeout
        HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

        await import.ProcessData();
        _log.LogInformation("Completed import");
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    _log.LogError(ex, "Import failed.");
    throw;
    }
}
```

I have verified with the debugger that records are effectively being read in the business logic, however when calling the REST endpoint in Swagger, it runs for an extended period of time and then simply times out, suggesting that there's an issue with the Network or with CORS.

Do you have any suggestions on how to best handle a large process like this via http? Thank you.

Comment: It could be also on the Database Connection string, it has a default don't remember what it is

Comment: The default timeout on a SQL connection is 30 seconds.  Add following to connection string : Connect Timeout=30.  Make larger.

Comment: Good point - trying that now.

Comment: Http has also its own default request timeout 30 seconds.

Comment: I would suggest getting rid of the data table step because it's unnecessary.

Comment: @jdweng "Connect Timeout" is the time it takes to connect to a server, not how long it takes to run the command. That value is specified elsewhere.

Comment: It is the command timeout :            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 30;

Comment: From architecture point of view your solution is inappropriate. Enterprise approach to handle heavy processing is to do it in background, using Windows services, Azure Worker Service, etc. Http requests should be as lightweight as possible, and should just schedule tasks for processing.